# hide/show div, custom post type condition

Tags: php

i can't get this function to work. I would like to change the css class based on the acf date field and current day. (sorry, this is my first post here)

```
function banner_change($match_id){
    $datamatch = get_post_meta($match_id, 'data', true);
    $today =  date("Y-m-d");
    
    if($datamatch >= $today ){
        return 'banner-si';
    }
    else if($datamatch < $today){
        return 'banner-no';
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `get_post_meta` return in terms of data?

Comment: return a date in format Y-m-d

Comment: is that a `date object` or `date string` though?

Comment: I don't know...is this ACF date picker https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/

Comment: According to [the top result here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ACF+date+picker&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - `"The Date Picker field returns a date string using the Return Format setting"` so perhaps you should use that returned string within a new instance of `date($datamatch)` before doing comparisons?!

Answer (score 0):

If the returned value from `get_post_meta` is a datestring rather than a proper date object you need somehow to convert that to a usable date object. It is usually most convenient to use the `DateTime` class as per the modified `banner_change` function below.

```
function banner_change( $id=false ){
    # fetch the date string
    $str=get_post_meta( $id, 'data', true );
    
    # create 1st DateTime using returned data
    $date=DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $str );
    
    #create 2nd DateTime as now.
    $now=new DateTime();
    
    # find difference in days between two dates
    $diff=$date->diff( $now )->d;
    
    # format return value
    return $diff > 0 ? 'banner-si' : 'banner-no';
}


$res=banner_change( 303 );
echo $res; // ex: banner-si
```